# How do I pass MYSQL link identifier as a string to mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql

Friends I have a big problem. I have several database connections. I have to use those connections dynamically in a mysql_query().
For example,

```
$db1=mysql_connect('port','username','password') or die("cannot connect to the database");
@mysql_select_db('db1') or die("Unable to select Database");

$db2=mysql_connect('port','username','password') or die("cannot connect to the database");
@mysql_select_db('db2') or die("Unable to select Database");
```

which connection to use is defined from a switch case.

```
switch(type){
case "1":
$link="$db1";
break;
case "2":
$link="$db2";
break;
}
```

my mysql_query is like this.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id='2'",$link);
```

unfortunately it's not working
it says **supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource**

I have tried following also but no luck

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id='2'".','.$link);
```

How can i do this? Any idea ??

Comment: Remove the quotes from `$link="$db1";` and `$link="$db2";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't transform the connection ids to strings in the `switch` statement by enclosing them with `"`! Just use the following:

```
switch(type){
  case "1":
    $link=$db1;
    break;
  case "2":
    $link=$db2;
    break;
}
```